# Solution of Linear First order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here's the question that I have [image]

I tried using the general solution of a linear differential equation. But unfortunately I am not getting the desired result. It feels there's a mistake in the problem itself.

Can anyone suggest something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can see [here on Math World](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/First-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html) a step-by-step derivation of the formula (eq. $5$ to $14$). The normal method for derivation is to use an integration factor $\mu$ with $\mu = e^{\int p\, \operatorname{d}x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is multiply both sides of the equation by a function $t(x)$ with the following property:

we basically get $ ty' + tPy = tQ$. We want to choose t(x) so that $ty' + tPy$ can be written as $\frac{d(ty)}{dx}$ which is $t'y + ty'$ the $ty'$ we have it in the equation. so all you have to do is put $t'y = tPy$ and solve for t. it's pretty straight forward from there